# Black Screen After Log In

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I've been playing Minecraft on a PC and just got a Mac laptop (OSX 10.7.5). Since the server I regularly play on has numerous mods (using Forge ModLoader), I decided to copy over my .minecraft files. I followed what instructions I could find and placed the `.minecraft` folder in my `~/Library/Application Support` folder and renamed it to `minecraft`. Upon launching Minecraft, the initial launch screen displays properly and I attempt to log in.

However, the Minecraft window proceeds to turn black. It still seems to be "responsive" (as clicking on the window doesn't make it turn gray and show the 'unresponsive' status), but it does not proceed from there. I don't see the Mojang loading screen nor do I make any other progress.

Most advice says to delete my minecraft folder and restart the launcher, but this will result in a fresh (as of now) 1.4.7 installation. The server I play on runs 1.4.6 along with a host of mods, so that option is a no-go.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a small folder inside the `minecraft/bin` folder called `natives`. This folder contains files that have platform-specific code. When you copied over your install, you copied over the Windows-native files in this folder. As a result, the game fails to run.

You can fix this by replacing the contents of that folder with the correct files from a valid 1.4.6 installation that was done on a Mac.

I'm not *entirely* certain how you can do that, but the files from a 1.4.7 install may work if in fact Mojang have not changed very much except for some classes in the main jar file. Archive your modded install somewhere else, install MC 1.4.7 fresh, and save the `natives` folder it generates somewhere convenient. Wipe the rest and put your modded install back in place, remove its Windows-based `natives` folder, and drop in your new one. See if it runs.

If using a 1.4.7 `natives` folder doesn't work though, one way to try would be to use [Minecraft Nostalgia](http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/800346-tool-mcnostalgia-212-with-gui-now-works-with-146/), which can downgrade the latest version of Minecraft to an arbitrary previous version. (I've used it for downgrading to 1.2.5 for modding purposes, but I haven't done it on a Mac. It appears to support Win/Mac/Linux though.)

You would safely archive your modded install, wipe it from the `minecraft/` folder, then run the vanilla launcher to get 1.4.7. Close it out, then run Minecraft Nostalgia, choosing 1.4.6 from the list. Once it's done the conversion, grab the `minecraft/bin/natives` folder for later. Wipe the rest, put your modded install in, and delete the `minecraft/bin/natives` folder that came from Windows. Finally, drop in your `natives/` folder gleaned from MC Nostalgia, cross your fingers, and launch!

Again, I've never had to do this, but it *should* work.

Comment: You should also be able to just delete the natives folder, and minecraft will automatically download the correct ones

Answer (score 7):

According to [Mojang](http://www.mojang.com/2012/12/minecraft-1-4-7-pre-release/):

> 1.4.6 clients can play on 1.4.7 servers, and 1.4.7 clients on 1.4.6 servers

So don't worry about the update, just go ahead and let the launcher redownload. It's even possible your bug was fixed in 1.4.7.

Mods should work too:

> [M]ods that have been updated for 1.4.6 should work in 1.4.7 too. The only affected file is the one called “qz”, which is the arrow projectile’s class.

Comment: This is probably true, but Forge (a mod loader) recognizes a difference in versioning and refuses to work.

Comment: @Yawus Well I can't help you with Forge, sorry, never used it. Talk to the Forge people about a workaround maybe?

Comment: @Yawus You should put that in your question, as it's sort of important to any solution that gets provided.

Comment: @fbueckert That is the sort of detail that answerers would know if they have any actual experience with mods in Minecraft. It's unreasonable to expect the asker to have to provide details that are logical consequences of what they've already provided. Similar to how the asker should not be obliged to explain that they're using a mouse when they say "… then I clicked on the button…"

Comment: @SevenSidedDie Um what? The OP said they were using mods. They did not specify a specific modloader, as each one works differently and has different update cycles.Some people don't even use modloaders at all. I don't see how "numerous mods" was supposed to automatically mean "Forge modloader".

Comment: @Yamikuronue Various polls indicate that somewhere around 80% of mods that require client-side installs (i.e. not Bukkit) use Forge. As a result, the likelihood that a client-side multiplayer install with "a lot" of mods requires Forge is only infinitesimally smaller than 100%.

Comment: @Yami Also fbueckert is often pedantic and picky, and pointing out where he's being *too* picky to the point of being unwelcoming is worthwhile to show the asker that they're not unwelcome. I, ah, – rereading I see that I caught you in the crossfire carelessly, so apologies for the general tack I took while objecting to fb's objection.

Comment: Hey, everybody - enough.  Please.  This isn't asking the answerer for clarification, it's just arguing.  Everybody take some time off and a deep breath, okay?

Comment: @SevenSidedDie I see no reason for insulting another user to try and get your point across. fbueckert wasn't trying to make the asker feel unwelcome. He was trying to help the asker refine his question to get better answers. Your being confrontational about his attempt to help is, in my opinion, more unwelcoming than his attempt to *help*.

Comment: Sorry about causing an argument, updated my question.

Comment: @Yawus No, I'm pretty sure that was entirely my fault. Sorry all. I'm not sure what bug crawled up my… to make that seem in the least like a sensible thing to write.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem and it took me a long time to fix it. Nothing anyone said did the trick but I did some extra stuff and it worked. I made a tutorial on it! here it is.

Comment: Hey, welcome to the site! Thanks for making a video for the fix. For the users of the site who might not have access to Youtube when they find this content, though, could you add a text summary of the video's solution to the problem?

Answer (score -2):

What I have done over all the times that i had this problem is go and delete your minecraft folder then reinstall the game again

Comment: This answer adds nothing new and nothing useful and in fact would potentially cause op additional problems. I would suggest answering new question that lack a good answer as a place to start.